# Getting the text of Ember.Button within the click method

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to find out the "Ember" way of getting the text label of an Ember.Button from within the click handler. Currently I have this (and it works) but I suspect there's a more "correct" way to do it:

```
App.RecentNameBtn = Em.Button.extend({
    click: function(e){
        App.tweetsArray.set('username', e.srcElement.innerText);
        App.tweetsArray.loadTweets();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a discussion whether `Ember.Button` should be [deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/436). Regardless of that, I would create an `App.userController` which holds the `username` and use the `{{action}}` helper in your view, see http://jsfiddle.net/bZ8fY/. It may look like an overhead but by using bindings you are much more flexible. I'd also suggest to move the logic out of the view into a controller.

**Handlebars:**

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#view App.TweetView}}
        <button {{action "loadTweets" target="App.userController"}}>
            {{username}}
        </button>
    {{/view}}
</script>​
```

​

**JavaScript:**

```js
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.userController = Ember.Object.create({
    username: 'emberjs',
    loadTweets: function(evt) {
        console.log( this.get('username') );
    }
});

App.TweetView = Ember.View.extend({
    usernameBinding: 'App.userController.username'
});
​
```

​

Comment: My app isn't quite as simple as just a button. Here's the larger preview: http://andymatthews.net/code/emberTweets/ After adding a user, a button shows up on the left side. When I click that button, I want to get the text label of the button and dump it into the text field.